# How to Initialize a sorted array in one line instead of creating the array and then sorting it?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a code like below:

```py
print([i if (ord(i)-97)%2 == 0 else i.upper() for i in input()].sort(reverse=True))
```

the result of this code is None, I couldn't understand why this happened?

Comment: `sort` always returns `None`. See the documentation.

Comment: It's a common misunderstanding that everything in Python must be in one line. It may sound quirky, but try with 2 lines. It may hurt your eyes for the first week or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.sort()` doesn't return the result. It sorts the given list in place, and so you have no access to it.

Instead, you can use `sorted`:

```
print(sorted([i if (ord(i)-97)%2 == 0 else i.upper() for i in input()], reverse=True))
```

Or call `sort` on a list you have assigned to a name:

```
lst = [i if (ord(i)-97)%2 == 0 else i.upper() for i in input()]
lst.sort(reverse=True)

print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was useful.